# How to push a file to sdcard of a device on AWS Device farm from Jenkins task

Tags: android, jenkins, aws-cli, aws-device-farm

I am running some instrumentation tests on AWS Device farm from my Jenkins task. Everything works fine. Now for some of the testcases, I need to put a file to sdcard of the device.

So, how to push a file to a sdcard of a device on "AWS Device Farm from jenkins machine. I have the AWS CI plugin installed on my jenkins machine.

Thanks for any help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You would use the [Extra Data parameter](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/devicefarm/latest/APIReference/API_ScheduleRunConfiguration.html) in the [ScheduleRun API](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/devicefarm/latest/APIReference/API_ScheduleRun.html) to push files to the device sdcard.

The [AWS Device Farm Jenkins plugin](https://github.com/awslabs/aws-device-farm-jenkins-plugin) does not support Extra Data uploads at this time. We are working on adding support but no ETA at this time. The plugin is open source so if you'd like to submit a pull request, we will be happy to take a look.

Comment: Hey Rohan.. Thanks for your comment. I just saw that we can push files as zip. So what actually happens on device when running test? Does it unzip the zip file and put it on sdcard root? Or in which location the zip is extracted on the device? If this zip meant for loading expansion files or for any files?

Comment: If it is an OBB file, we extract the contents to the root of the sdcard. Any other file is placed as is to that location. See the FAQ item named ["I’d like to supply media or other data for my app to consume. How do I do that?"](https://aws.amazon.com/device-farm/faq/).